# linking events two way

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
    $('#Element1').event(function() {
        $('#Element2').event({ prop: $('#Element1').someMethod() });
    });
```

Now the Element 2 responds on an Event of Element1 and when Element 1 property changes. How to do it vice-versa in an optimum manner.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Philippe..There are two elements on the form..I am trying to bind an eventtwo way so that if either of the control changes, the other one gets affected. I hope iwas clear enough

Comment: so for example if i have textbox1 and textbox 2..when i start typing in textbox 1, textbox 2 should automatically have the same chars inserted..similarly wehn i type in textbox 2, textbox1 should get upated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the problem you describe in your comment, I don't think you'd need such complicated event-driven code. Here's my solution:

```
$("#input1, #input2").keyup(function (e) {
    $("#input1, #input2").val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the easiest solution:

```
$("#textbox1").keyup(function() { $("#textbox2").val($(this).val()); });
$("#textbox2").keyup(function() { $("#textbox1").val($(this).val()); });
```